# New Self Build Replacement PC

Tags: desktop, case, mini-pc, music, ubuntu

Currently I have an Acer Revo One RL85. Physical dimensions are circa 150 mm tall, 100 x 100mm. It is perfect for the size, but has max' 8gb RAM. I am looking to build a new machine.
I want something with the same physical footprint and **not** a black box. This will be visible in a living room, part PC, part media server, running Ubuntu [I am running Ubuntu now].
Can anyone suggest a case that will be circa 150 mm tall, 100 x 100mm and not black, not NUC ? The Akasa Turing is out of stock with no dates for availabilty.
Thanks All.
P.

Comment: Hmmm. As far as I know, non-nuc cases have to be at least 170mm*170mm*+-100mm (ITX). Why not give it 16GB ram and paint it?

Comment: Or you can get an NZXT H1 or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfugYtBAjOg